# escape_javascript tag is not working in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller

```
def upload_file
    @invoice = Invoice.create(:invoice=>  user_params["invoices_attributes"].first["invoice"],:temp_id=>session[:temp_id])
    respond_to do |format|
            format.js 
    end
end
```

and view

> upload_file.js.erb

`$('#deposite_rows').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'deposite') %>");`

> _deposite.html.erb

This is test view

But this is not showing on view but when i saw on in response of firefug i getting `$('#deposite_rows').html("This is test view")`

Why I am getting proper text on view in `rails4`

Comment: Please provide alter-net solution for that

Comment: `$('#deposite_rows').html("This is test view")` is the correct response to be seeing in firebug. What's the actual problem? Is the `#deposite_rows` element updating with "This is a test view"?

Comment: @MikeCampbell, Problem is that `#deposite_rows` is not updating element with 'This is a test view"?'

Comment: if you enter the same code in the firebug console does it work? I suspect it's a problem with the jQuery rather than anything to do with Rails.

Comment: @MikeCampbell Which Jquery version is required

Comment: That code will work with any jQuery version.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I have used `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41712/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-vijay-chouhan)