# What is the better way to use escape_javascript in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `escape_javascript` in rails3 but I dont know how to use `escape_javascript` in rails4.

I have read from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-support

It is saying

`Rails 4.0 removes the j alias for ERB::Util#json_escape since j is already used for ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper#escape_javascript.`

Comment: The quote seems to be fairly self-explanatory, so I'm not sure what you're asking. You can continue to use `escape_javascript` as you have in Rails 3.

Comment: @MikeCampbell please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106091/escape-javascript-tag-is-not-working-in-rails4